# Estimation of the Probability of $\left\{|X^{(i)}-X^{(n)}|\le2\delta\text{ for all }i\in[n,m-1]\text{ and }|X^{(m)}-X^{(n)}|>2\delta\right\}$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

### Assumptions

Let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of independent real-valued random variables and $$B_{m,n}:=\left\{\left|X^{(i)}-X^{(n)}\right|\le2\delta \text{ for all }i\in[n,m-1]\text{ and }\left|X^{(m)}-X^{(n)}\right|>2\delta\right\}$$ where $$X^{(n)}:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$$
and $\delta>0$. Moreover, let $X^{(n)}$ converge stochastically to some $X$.

---

### Problem

I don't understand why it holds $$\Pr\left[B_{m,n}\right]\le\frac{\Pr\left[B_{m,n}\cap\left\{\left|X-X^{(n)}\right|>\delta\right\}\right]}{\Pr\left[\left|X-X^{(m)}\right|\le\delta\right]}\tag{1}$$

---

### My Ideas

It's easy to see (from the triangle inequality) that we've got $$\left|X-X^{(n)}\right|\ge\left|\underbrace{\left|X^{(n)}-X^{(m)}\right|}_{>2\delta}-\left|X^{(m)}-X\right|\right|\;\;\;\text{on }B_{m,n}$$ Hence, $$B_{m,n}\cap\left\{\left|X-X^{(m)}\right|\le\delta\right\}\subseteq B_{m,n}\cap\left\{\left|X-X^{(n)}\right|>\delta\right\}\tag{2}$$ However, I'm unable to derive $(1)$ from $(2)$ and the assumptions.

Comment: Please note: $$\left\{f>\alpha\right\}:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)>\alpha\right\}$$ for $f:\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deduce (1) from (2), notice that the event $\left\{\left|X-X^{(m)}\right|\leqslant\delta\right\}=\left\{\left|\sum_{j=m+1}^{+\infty}X_j   \right|\leqslant\delta\right\}$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $X_i,i\geqslant m+1$ (up to a null set).
Indeed, using the stochastic convergence, we can find a sequence $n_j\uparrow\infty$ such that $X-X^{(m)}=\lim_{j\to\infty}X^{(n_j)}-X^{(m)}$ almost everywhere.

Thus, the event $\left\{\left|X-X^{(m)}\right|\leqslant\delta\right\}$ is independent of $B_{m,n}$.

Comment: I don't get it: Why is $X^{(m)}$ measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_i,i\ge m+1)$? Does the stochastic convergence imply the measurability?

Comment: The random variable $X-X^{ (m)}$ is measurable with respect to  $\mathcal F_m:=\sigma(X_i,i\ge m+1)$ , not $X_m$ (this random variable is actually independent of $\mathcal F_m$).